# Login program from an external txt file

Tags: python, python-3.x

Im trying to make a login program that save and check the username and password to an external text file. It writes and separates it inside the text file but when I try to check the user input for the login it always output the wrong input massage, I couldn't figure out why it's not matching. I checked the for loop variable values and it matches my inputs but still tells me that my inputs are wrong.

```
import csv

def login():
    username= input("Please enter your user name")
    password= input("Please enter your password")

    Me = open("users.txt", "r")
    found_it = False

    for line in Me:
        Search = line.split(",")
        print(Search[0]+Search[1])
        if username == Search[0] and password == Search[1]:
            found_it = True
            break

    if found_it == True:
        print("you are in")
        Me.close()
    else:
        print("wrong user or pass")
        Me.close()

def register():
    name= input("please enter your name")
    pas = input("please enter your pass")

    with open ("users.txt", "a") as New_reg:
        writer = csv.writer(New_reg)
        writer.writerow([name, pas])
        New_reg.close()

def menu():
    menu= input("Login 1?\nregister 2? ")
    if menu == "1":
        login()
    elif menu == "2":
       register()
    else:
        print("try again")
        menu()


menu()
#------------
#this is the output
#Login 1?
#register 2?1
#Please enter your user namesaf
#Please enter your password111
#saf111

#wrong user or pass

#Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Try printing your username and password for debugging purposes, there might be a new line character at the end of it.

Comment: I copied your code and it is working fine for me. I did use ```test,test``` in my .txt file and it prints "you are in" for me.

Comment: There is a newline character at the end of every line in the text file. This will read the password as `111\n`. To avoid this you can strip newlines, although a better solution would be to just use csv.reader(Me), as this will read each line in as a list, exactly the way you wrote it.

Comment: I think there is some spaces when you save your user id and password which makes the matching an issues, better strip yourn striungs and convert them to lower case before matching again.

Comment: Thank you mattrea6 the newline was causing the problem. I used .strip() to fix it. Thank you all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a newline character at the end of the line. You just have to trim the newline character of and you program will work as intended:

```py
for line in Me:
    Search = line.replace("\n", "").split(",")
    print(Search[0]+Search[1])
    if username == Search[0] and password == Search[1]:
        found_it = True
        break
```

We are just replacing the newline character `\n` with an empty string using the `replace` function right before you split the string.

Or as you found out by yourself, we can remove spaces and newline from a string using the `strip` function:

```py
for line in Me:
    Search = line.strip().split(",")
    print(Search[0]+Search[1])
    if username == Search[0] and password == Search[1]:
        found_it = True
        break
```